# Auto-add paragraphs to custom field?

Tags: custom-field, php, functions

hey guys,
is it possible to format text in a custom field input box automatically with paragraphs?

e.g. like the normal text-widget that has the option to say "auto-add paragraphs" when there is a linebreak.

I just want my blogauthors to spare typing 
 at the end of every line in a custom field!

is there a way to do so?

update:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $sidebar_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar-title', $single = true);
                    $sidebar_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar-text', $single = true); ?>

                    <?php if ( $sidebar_title !== '' && $sidebar_text !== '' ) { ?>
                        <li class="widget-container widget-light-blue custom">  
                            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php echo wpautop($sidebar_title, $br); ?></h3>
                            <?php echo wpautop($sidebar_text, $br); ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `apply_filters( 'the_content', $var );` when outputting your custom field? You don't really want to **save** the extra paragraphs, otherwise you'll end up seeing them when editing the custom field. This is not what happens with WordPress.

If you're not happy with what `the_content` does (it does a lot of things including `wpautop`) then create a custom filter like this:

```
// Assuming $var is your custom field value
add_filter( 'my_custom_filter', 'wpautop' );
echo apply_filters( 'my_custom_filter', $var );
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass the user-input data through `wpautop()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)) when you save those data to the DB?

EDIT:

You should be doing something like the following, to validate/sanitize the user input:

```
/* Function to validate, sanitize, and save post metadata. */
function mytheme_save_custom_metadata(){

  global $post;

  $valid_custom_field_input = wp_kses( wpautop( $_POST['custom_meta_field'] ) );

  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_meta_field', $valid_custom_field_input );
}
/* Add our function to the save_post hook. */
add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_custom_metadata');
```

Notice that I put wrapped the user input in `wpautop()` before passing through `wp_kses()`.

Comment: really nice idea, however won't work: `<?php echo wpautop($sidebar_text, $br); ?>`

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You're trying to *echo the output* using wpautop(); I suggested *passing the userdata through wpautop() upon save*.

Comment: Question: what is the code for your function to save the userdata to the database?

Comment: @Chip- do you actually want to save data with the html though? I think you just want to pass it through when you output it to the front end template.

Comment: @Milo: what's the harm in that? I'm assuming that the data are already being filtered.

Comment: I don't get it! How can i pass that upon save? I don't have any handwritten code, i'm just using the normal custom fields function. see my update.

Comment: Where/how are your custom field data being *saved*. You've posted *output*, not *input*.

Comment: See my latest edit, where I provide an example custom-field input validation function.

Comment: @Chip- WordPress only uses it internally when data is output to template, I figured that was the proper way. I try not to pollute my data with markup when I can avoid it. @mathiregister- in your wpautop function, $br should be a boolean or integer: `wpautop($sidebar_title, 1);`

Comment: Good catch on using `$br`, which is almost certainly an undefined variable. The `wpautop()` call is probably evaluating that as `false`, which would be the opposite effect of what the OP wants. The OP should try replacing `$br` with `true`, or simply omitting it altogether, since it defaults to `true`, anyway.